# How to create leaning list items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal `RecyclerView` which looks like this (obviously)

```
-------------------------------
|     |     |     |     |     |
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |
|     |     |     |     |     |
-------------------------------
```

I want to do this:

```
------------------------------
|      /     /     /     /    |
|  1  /  2  /  3  /  4  /  5  |
|    /     /     /     /      |
-------------------------------
```

What is the best way to create a `RecyclerView` like this?

Note: I'm not trying to create a leaning divider. I am trying to create a leaning layout. By leaning I mean masked not rotated. Items should have a `match_parent` `ImageView` and a `TextView`. Both should look straight, not rotated. Also pay attention to the first and last item please.

Here is a sample:

[image: sample]

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please clarify more or provide an image of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've added a sample image

Comment: @osrl, cool! And great question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Squint](https://github.com/IntruderShanky/Squint)

Create an layout xml with the below code. This layout file renders a single row in recycler view by displaying image and text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:squint="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.intrusoft.squint.DiagonalView
        android:id="@+id/diagonalView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        squint:angle="10"
        squint:diagonalDirection="bottom_to_top"
        squint:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/diagonalView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/diagonalView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/diagonalView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

After writing custom adapter, you should prepare the RecyclerView as follows.

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false); // make it horizontal

 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

After applying these operations successfully, I got an image like this.
[image]

This solution may not be the perfect solution. There are some defective spots such as  ***android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"***. At least it can give you an idea.

Comment: Yes that's not the perfect solution but you gave me the idea. You deserved the bounty. eyvallah ;)

Comment: I had some problems with negative margins. So I used an `ItemDecoration` to overlap items. Maybe you should edit your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29067942/1120126 I also used (and edited) this library https://github.com/florent37/DiagonalLayout/ because I was already using a custom ImageView.

Comment: Negative margin is not a healthy solution. I'm glad you found the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer for your problem but i would recommend to create your own DividerItemDecoration.

For more info check this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html

Comment: `DividerItemDecoration` is specifically for dividers only. I think you meant `ItemDecoration` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html

Comment: I'm not trying to create a leaning divider. I am trying to create a leaning layout. By leaning I mean masked.

Comment: @osrl so do not use `DividerItemDecoration` but `ItemDecoration` as Pztar said

Comment: How this is gonna mask the items?

Comment: it will not mask, it will re-position them so they overlap each other, the masking has to be done in a custom item view

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't really do a `RecyclerView`, since those views can't overlap. At this point, you may want to consider extending a horizontal `ScrollView`, and stitch your images and other elements into one long view that you scroll by overriding the `onDraw` method. You can handle click events in the `onTouch` method override. This looks like a pretty big project thought, especially if you have a lot of images and have to manage memory.

Comment: Dividing line should include items' imageViews. Also this way line cannot be clicked.