# How to draw an Android Trapezoidal

Tags: android

I am an Android developer. When I started the project, I needed to put a trapezoid in my layout, but I asked questions because I didn't know how to make it. I want to make it look like the picture below.

[image]

What should I do? I don't think it's a good idea to put an image

Comment: have you tried drawing in a canvas? https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Comment: Well, I also thought about drawing on canvas.
However, I was worried that it was more efficient than drawing a layout.

Comment: how about using vector drawable ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42928916/6914992. it also have a link how to understand it under the  comment :)

Comment: Right! This is what I wanted. Thank you very much.